# Simulate Enter key on clicking space key

Tags: extjs, combobox

I want to select and deselct combobox items using space key. In the existing functionality it happens with Enter key.
I have the following code which is not working and giving error deep inside the sencha files.Here me is the combobox.

```
keydown: function (me, e, eOpts) {
    me.keyPressed = e.getKey();
    if (me.keyPressed == 32) {
        e.keyCode = Ext.EventObject.ENTER;
        this.fireEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is to modify the key bindings of the KeyNavigation of the picker.

```
listeners:{
    afterrender:function(combo) {
        var picker = combo.getPicker(),
            navModel = picker.getNavigationModel(),
            map = navModel.keyNav.map,
            existingBindings = Ext.Array.filter(map.bindings, function(binding) {
                return binding.key === Ext.event.Event.SPACE; 
            };
        map.removeBinding(existingBindings[0]);
        map.addBinding({
                key: Ext.event.Event.SPACE,
                fn: navModel.onKeyEnter,
                scope: navModel
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alexander. This code works for the first time when I click space, it correctly deselects the selected item. After that when I click the space key, instead of selecting the deselected item, it moves the cursor in the display area ahead(the focus here goes to the display list area instead of the item being selected)